# Is it possible to install Picasa on a user selected file and drive?

Tags: windows-7, picasa

I have installed Picasa after upgrading to Windows 7, and now I have quite a mixup. 
I wouldn't mind reinstalling and building Picasa databases again, but didn't notice any way to select a specific drive or folder to install the user files.
Is this possible?
thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly is the "mixup"?

Answer (score 1):

hmm how are you re installing picasa I just downloaded the latest installer and on the first screen it shows the licence the minute i accepted that it shows a screen title Choose Install location have I missed something here let me know if this helps.